# Swagger has stopped picking up my endpoints

Tags: c#, swagger

I had a bunch of controllers with some endpoints and they were all ok in swagger. Then I realised that the controllers were not using Web Api 2 but MVC.

the Classes were declared in the form:

```
[Apicontroller]
public class myController : ControllerBase...

[HttpGet("routeName")
public async Task<IActionResult> .....
```

I changed them to:

```
[RoutePrefix("[my]")]
public class myController : ApiController

[HttpGet]
[Route("myroute")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult>......
```

and now the methods do not appear in swagger.

Swagger is declared in my program.cs file:

```
.....
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
.....
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.MapControllers();
```

Does anyone know why swagger is no longer picking up my endpoints?

Comment: please add the remaining dependencies in the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are running in Development mode. If you are releasing to prod env will be Production
2. Go to swagger/v1/swagger.json for your website and check if there is any errors.

Comment: Im running in debug mode,opeing this file all I see is  `{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "VisualStores",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "paths": { }, }`